# Find the orthogonal complement of the plane $2x+y+3z=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I solved this problem following this process:

Subspace: $S=sp([2, 1, 3])$

Nullspace:

$$2x_{1}+x_{2}+3x_{3}=0 \\
x_{1}=-\frac{x_{2}}{2}-\frac{3x_{3}}{2}$$

$r=x_{2}$ and $s=x_{3}$

So

$$x=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{r}{2}-\frac{3}{2}s\\ r
\\ s \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 2
\\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\ 0
\\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}$$

$r,s\in\mathbb{R}$

Finally the orthogonal complement is

$$S^{\bot}=sp
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 2
\\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\ 0
\\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}$$

Is my process correct?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the equation of the plane.

The equation of the plane $2x+y+3z=0$ means that the vectors $(x,y,z)^T$ of the plane are such that $(2,1,3)(x,y,z)^T=0$ this means that they are vectors such that their dot product with $(2,1,3)$ is zero, i.e. vectors orthogonal to such a vector.

So the orthogonal complement in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the plane is the stright line that contains the vector $(2,1,3)^T$, i.e. $(x,y,z)^T=t(2,1,3)^T \; \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It might be worth adding that the orthogonal complement of a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ must be one-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

The othogonal complement of a subspace (in any dimensions) has codimension equal to the dimension of the subspace. This means here, the orthogonal complement has dimension $1$. It is generated by the vector $\;\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}$, normal to the plane.